# Difference between these two sentences?

Tags: articles, subject-verb-agreement

I got confused between these two sentences:

> **The** number of poisonous snakes **is/are** there on the tree.
>
> **A** number of poisonous snakes **is/are** there on the tree.

Could anybody explain the difference in semantics of these two sentences. Also what to take verb with these two variations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first sentence is quite artificial:

> The number of poisonous snakes **is** there on the tree.

This means that there is a number painted or written or attached to the tree. That number tells you how many poisonous snakes there are somewhere. It doesn't make sense without a context. It wouldn't even make much sense given a context that tries to make sense of it.

> A number of poisonous snakes is/are there on the tree.

Some native speakers will argue that this sentence should take a singular copula, **is**, because the grammatical subject is *A number*, which is single. Others will argue that it should take a plural, **are**, because the notional subject, *snakes*, is plural. Still others will argue that it should take **are** because the word comes immediately after a plural noun, so it feels and sounds better as a plural.

Here's [a grammar page that explains the problem a little bit](http://data.grammarbook.com/blog/singular-vs-plural/the-number-vs-a-number/).

I would argue two things. First, the sentence should be this:

> A number of poisonous snakes are on the tree. [*there* is superfluous, IMHO]

and, second, that when you write a sentence like this that you're not sure of, it should be changed to something like this:

> There are {many /some /a few [CHOOSE ONE]} poisonous snakes on the tree.

Comment: +1; I appreciate that you presented the case for both *is* and *are*, and offered a simpler rewrite!